# Shadow on bottom part of CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView which has 6 cells. First 4 one is seeing, but users need to scroll down to see down part. I want a shadow where I show in red circle.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiwOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

For shadow you need to do something like this

```
self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Comment: Won't this shade the entire collection view?

Comment: I make it like self.mCollectionView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.mCollectionView.bounds, cornerRadius: self.mCollectionView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift :

Works like a charm ..

```
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    self.collectionView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: I have the same code. BUT the shadow scrolls with the items inside the colllectionView